# How to join two table with aggregate for Deno and MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, join, aggregate, deno

Nowadays, I am learning Deno and I try simple app with Deno and MongoDb. So far, everything is going perfectly. But today, I want to join two tables with aggregate function. My sample code is here:

```
const result = await articles.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "authors",
        localField: "oid",
        foreignField: "author_id",
        as: "author",
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$author",
    },
  ]);
  req.send(result);
```

I want an output like the one below. But for now, although there are only 3 Articles in my database, it matches these authors with all authors and brings a total of 6 records.

[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APQHt.png)

I think the problem is caused by the following reason. But I'm not sure.

```
// My output id format
"_id": {
      "$oid": "5ed7abfc00f94b9c0048ba5e"
},

// what will be written in the localfield field in this section
$lookup: {
        from: "authors",
        localField: "oid",
        foreignField: "author_id",
        as: "author",
},
```

I'm waiting for your help.

Comment: change `oid` to `_id`, `oid` is just an Abbreviation for ObjectId.

Comment: I did this but an empty array returned

Comment: According to the names you gave it also seems like you need to switch between `localField` and `foreignField`.

Comment: I tried that method. Again, the empty array returned. I hope the error's **_id** value is an object and it contains the  **$oid**  variable.

Comment: The only other reason i can think of is `author_id` not being `oid` but `string`

Comment: From the output, it seems `author_id` is a `string` as @TomSlabbaert suggested, you should change it to oid (by using `new ObjectID(value)` when inserting it [ref](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html) ), then use `localField: 'authorId', foreignField: '_id'`

Comment: i have a question, how did you insert the author id inside the article? i tried to search, but i only get mongoose solutions.. thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found the right solution to this problem yet, but I solved it a bit by doing as below.

```
  var result = await articles.find();
  for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
    result[i].author = await authors.findOne({ _id: { $oid: result[i].author_id } });
  }
  req.send(result);
```

My problem is due to ObjectId. Deno does not support this feature yet. I believe they will solve the problem soon.

Comment: Did you found any better options?